# How to offer files in volume for download via servlet?

Tags: java, docker, tomcat

I have files on a volume that I want users to be able to download via a servlet on a tomcat container.

I've created a volume and a container

```
$ sudo docker volume create tomcat-volume
$ docker run -d -p 8080:8080 --name tomcat \
  -v tomcat-volume:/usr/local/tomcat \
  tomcat:9.0.10-jre8
```

and deploy my `.war` file via `localhost:8080` in the browser(after editing `conf/tomcat-users.xml` and `webapps/manager/META-INF/context.xml` to get access rights).

`sudo docker volume inspect tomcat-volume` states the mountpoint to be `/var/lib/docker/volumes/tomcat-volume/_data/`

The directory `temp` already contains `saveToDelete.tmp` and I've added two custom files to be sure.
Relevant code from my Servlet is:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html"); 
    PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
    pw.append("<!DOCTYPE html>\n");
    pw.append("<html>\n");
    pw.append("<body>\n");

    String link;
    File[] files = (new File("/usr/local/tomcat/temp/")).listFiles();
    for(File f: files) {
        link = String.format("<a href=\"%s\" download>%s</a>", f.getAbsolutePath(), f.getName());
        pw.append(link);
        pw.append("<br>\n");
    }
    pw.append("</body>\n");
    pw.append("</html>\n");
}
```

which generates:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<a href="/usr/local/tomcat/temp/safeToDelete.tmp" download>safeToDelete.tmp</a><br>
<a href="/usr/local/tomcat/temp/hej.png" download>hej.png</a><br>
<a href="/usr/local/tomcat/temp/hej.html" download>hej.html</a><br>
</body>
</html>
```

indicating that I do have the right address. However I cannot download these files but get 404 not found. I have made sure that the files are readable to everyone:

```
$ sudo ls -l /var/lib/docker/volumes/tomcat-volume/_data/temp
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     4 Apr 22 11:31 hej.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2962 Apr 22 11:31 hej.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 Jun 20  2018 safeToDelete.tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm OP and I solved this with a second download servlet.
The loop is modified to call the servlet:

```
    for(File f: files) {
        String target = "DownloadServlet?" + f.getName();
        link = String.format("<a href=\"%s\" download>%s</a>", target, f.getName());
        pw.append(link);
        pw.append("<br>\n");
    }
```

Relevant code in `DownloadServlet`:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String filename = request.getQueryString();

    response.setContentType("APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM");

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\"");

    FileInputStream fl = new FileInputStream("/usr/local/tomcat/temp/" + filename);

    int i;
    while ((i = fl.read()) != -1) {
        out.write(i);
    }

    fl.close();
    out.close();
}
```